# Unable to fetch the data from getAttribute on button call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting a new ReactJS project where I have to get the details of `userfeed` and add it to list and delete them as needed. I have implemented the list, for deleting the single `userfeed` I am passing custom attribute, when the delete button is clicked, I am unable to get it's attribute in my main component.

Below is my code for `maincomponent.js` function which I am trying to call

(note : `userfeed` and `maincompnent` are different components)

```html
//i am intislizing this in constructor
 this.deleteFeed = this.deleteFeed.bind(this);
 this.deleteFeedAction = this.deleteFeedAction.bind(this);
 
 
deleteFeedAction(e){
    
    let updateIndex=e.target.getAttribute('index');
    let feed_id = e.target.getAttribute('data'); // unable to get this data
  }
  
   deleteFeed(e){


      confirmAlert({
        title: '',                        
        message: 'Are you sure to delete an iteration?',               
        childrenElement: () => '',       
        confirmLabel: 'Delete',                          
        cancelLabel: 'Cancel',                            
        onConfirm: () => this.deleteFeedAction(e),    
        onCancel: () => '',      
      })
 

  }
  
<UserFeed feedData = {this.state.data}  deleteFeed = {this.deleteFeed} convertTime={this.convertTime} name={this.state.name}/>
```

Bellow is my `userFeed.js`

```html
<div className="small-12 medium-2 columns add-friend">
       <div className="add-friend-action"> 
       <button className="button secondary small" onClick={this.props.deleteFeed} data={feedData.iterationid} value={index} >
              <i className="fa fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Delete
       </button>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add the code of UserFeed component also

Comment: I am only making a button call on userFeed.js i have mentioned that in the question. rest of the operations are done in mainComponent.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making things complex

Change

```
   <button className="button secondary small" onClick={this.props.deleteFeed} data={feedData.iterationid} value={index} >
```

To

Here you pass event and iterationid as params to deleteFeed function

```
  <button className="button secondary small" onClick={(e) => this.props.deleteFeed(e, feedData.iterationid)} data={feedData.iterationid} value={index} >
```

Take below code and replace

Here you access feedId like below

```
    deleteFeedAction(e, feedId){
       let updateIndex=e.target.getAttribute('index');
       console.log(feedId);//you will get feedId here
    }

     deleteFeed(e, feedId){
           confirmAlert({
                title: '',                        
                message: 'Are you sure to delete an iteration?',               
                childrenElement: () => '',       
                confirmLabel: 'Delete',                          
                cancelLabel: 'Cancel',                            
                onConfirm: () => this.deleteFeedAction(e, feedId),    
                onCancel: () => '',      
             })
        }
```

Especially when iterating items in loop and for edit/delete of an item you directly pass item id to handler function and access it

Comment: I made the above changes , in deleteFeed method i am getting an error saying feedId not defined. because i have not defined this feedId in my main component.

Comment: You didn’t understand my answer. You need to make changes as it is as I suggested in my answer. Share your updated code in question

Comment: sorry for the mistake. i missed a single change while updating code. code works like charm . Thank you

Comment: I am able to get the data as parameter but not as attribute. is there any way i can get it as attribute?

Comment: You can get using e.target.data

Answer (score 0):

Since you have children elements in the `<button>` tag, the problem is probably that the click event gets fired is not from `button` (which has `data` attribute) but the icon (`<i>`) or even the plain text. To see if this is actually the case, add `console.log(e.target)` in the `deleteFeedAction` function to see which element triggers the click event.

To fix this, and considering what you need to delete the feed is provided in the `maincomponent.js` level, what you can do is to pass whatever you need in the `deleteFeed` function. If all you need is `iteration`, then you can change `UserFeed` to be as the following:

```
<UserFeed feedData = {this.state.data}  deleteFeed = {() => this.deleteFeed(this.state.data.iterationid)} convertTime={this.convertTime} name={this.state.name}/>
```